# Restarting counter before it has expired on Programmable Interval Timer (8254)

Tags: c, assembly, x86

I am writing an preemptive kernel in C and assembly. I've been looking at and setting up timer interrupts through the PIT and the PIC but one thing I am utterly unable to find an answer on.

We have initilized the 8254 chip to be counting on counter 0 in mode 2. We set it to fire an interrupt on IR0 on the PIC every 10 ms. After that we enable the IR0 on the PIC and things work as intended.

However lets say at certain conditions we want to alter the time that the PIT fires at by feeding it a new value. Or just restart the counter midcounting.

The intel manual for the chip has some detail on the gate and using it to restart the counter by getting a rising edge on the gate.

THe manual also says that if we give the counter a new value it doesn't reset the counter until after the current counting sequence is finished unless a trigger (rising edge on the gate) happens before the counting is over.

The manual also says that sending a new CW to the chip would reset the counter, however I don't believe this is the optimal way of restarting or altering the counter.

So the question is, how would this be done in either c or assembly? (We got full write access whenever we want).

Comment: If I recall correctly, the 8254 has to be reset in order to change the  counter while it is in mid-cycle when setup for periodic interrupts. Is this really needed? The other issue is that the interrupt is a bit out of sync with the readable values of the counter (if it's close to a an interrupt boundary, the usual fix is to re-read the counter).

Comment: @rcgldr You don't need to reset the whole 8254 if I understand it correctly, as you can reset just one of its 3 timers with a new CW but this isn't optimal afaik. However the manual does state that the counter will go from the initial value on the next CLK pulse if it gets a rising edge on the gate pin. The same applies to counting from a new value, if the gate pin gets a rising edge it should start counting from the new value on the next CLK pulse. So this should be doable without reseting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To not leave a question unanswered and as I've somewhat of an answer I'll answer it myself.

As far as I've understood the chip has 3 counters but only counter 2 (we start counting at 0) has the gate pin connected (and this one has it connected to the speaker). As a result counter 0 which is the real timer counter doesn't have a connection on the gate which means we can't cause a trigger on it after sending it a new value.

This means that sending a value to it and then restarting it on the value before the timer is up is impossible without sending it new ICW.

In case we want to reset the timer when we get out of an interrupt caused by the 8259 chip which the 8254 is connected to at the end of the handling of that interrupt (that is we don't want the time to be running during the actual interrupt) we would be best of changing the mode to mode 0 which doesn't restart the timer on terminal count and then just manually restart it with the time we want to use for it each time we are about to end and interrupt.